# Regex to match groups only before period

Tags: regex

I wonder what is wrong with [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/bFjWoC/1).
What I would expect is that `(\d+)` matches 3 groups of digits before the period.

That is, I expect the three matches: `1`, `2`, `3` but not `0`.

If I only write `\d+` I get four matches, but I need this only before the period and have the three digits as the result.

What would be the correct way to achieve this ?

Comment: Laszlo, you accepted an answer that matches 1 or more digits before any char but a line break char. You wrote you need to match digit only before a period, and only my answer provides that solution. How about accepting the appropriate solution?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're actually right, I had to further tweak that one. But unfortunately the solution you suggested seems to have a pattern error https://regex101.com/r/gH06yF/1 unless I am missing something here.

Comment: [There is no issue](https://regex101.com/r/gH06yF/2) in the **pattern**, it all depends how you are using it. `/` is not a special regex metacharacter and only needs to be escaped when `/` is used as a regex delimiter. What is your programming language? (Also, I already provided a regex101 demo link in my answer proving it works)

Comment: What is the regex flavor? As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yesterday I already wanted to update my comment saying "yes, this is the correct solution" only editing comment was not allowed due to a time lock. So yes, if I select Python as Regex flavor, there is not pattern failure.

Comment: You may use any delimiter with PHP/PCRE, my favorite is `~`, and it will work, too. In JS/Ruby, if you use a constructor notation, you do not  need to escape `/` either. So if you use this in Python, you are surely unlikely to ever need to escape `/`s in regex patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider matching digits and `/` within the lookahead:

```
\d+(?=[/\d]*\.)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bFjWoC/2).

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits...
- `(?=[/\d]*\.)` - *immediately* followed with

  - `[/\d]*` - 0 or more `/` or digit chars
  - `\.` - a dot.

Alternatively, if you just want to match any chunks of digits that are followed with a `.` somewhere to the right of the digits, just use `.*`:

```
\d+(?=.*\.)
```

Here, the 1+ digits are matched only when followed with any 0+ chars followed with a dot.

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/bFjWoC/4)

Answer (score 0):

Since want you to match numbers that are followed by *some* character, you can simply use a lookahead that matches something:

```
(\d+)(?=.)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bFjWoC/3

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew pointed out, this solution is partial, not fully matching my needs